# Is there an English word(s) which can act as a synonym for the words parent, guardian, or carer?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am opposed to referring to the person(s) who looks after a child, especially full-time, but I want a generic word ideally, as *parent*, *carer*, or *guardian*, as I want a noun that is inclusive, one which can refer to the person(s) who is caring for a child, but who *may* not be their parent(s) or whatever.

Frankly, using *parent, guardian, and or carer* to try to be as correct as possible can be a little bit of an irritation, so is there a modern word which can be used to refer to a child who is being cared for by someone who may or may not have any legal, biological, etc., relationship to them, but is still unequivocally inclusive, so once one knows of what relationship the child is to the person(s) who is caring for them they can use the parent, carer, or guardian, etc., configurations?

According to my research, the closest words which I could fine were *charge* and *ward*, however I think using these in, for example, a letter from, say, a school or a similar institution to people who are caring for children regardless of their relationship to the child(ren) for whom they are caring sounds far, far too outdated, as families nowadays are far more diverse, thus I think we need a language which reflects that.

Any (preferably modern and (mostly) commonplace) suggestions?

Comment: *guardian* ***is*** the word.

Comment: *guardian*, as Jim mentioned, fits perfectly.   Irritation?  Not at all. Use it.

Comment: You mentioned a letter from a school, but wouldn't a school be writing only to a parent or legal guardian?

Comment: Guardian implies a legal responsibility. How about nanny?

Comment: @Jim As another user has said, though, Jim, doesn't the word 'guardian' denote a legal relationship? What if someone isn't legally authorized to look after someone, but they are? As I said, I was looking for a typically inclusive word.

Comment: @OneWhoBelievesInPeace - The way I see it, ***legal*** guardian  means it has legal guardianship.  That’s why they say *legal guardian*

Comment: Most forms and other documents that I have seen refer to "Parent or Guardian". If I was completing a form referring to my own children I would be really confused by seeing only "Guardian", no matter how accurate it may be legally. Possible alternatives would be "Responsible Adult" or "Contact Person" either of which would cover all the possibilites.

Comment: How about [_childcarer_](https://www.lexico.com/definition/childcarer)? _Lexico_ definition: "A person who looks after children, either as a paid worker or as a parent."

Comment: @BoldBen - Yes,  the usual terminology is “Parent or [legal] guardian” and it would seem odd to deviate from it.  But I do think your “responsible adult” is pretty good.  But even then I think I’ve seen it as “parent or responsible adult”